# MongoDB + Python, unexpected numeric types

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, types, pymongo

I have the following Python code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/")["admin"]
collection = db["collection_test"]
collection.insert_one({"key1": 1000000000.1, "key2": 1.1})
doc = collection.find_one()
print(type(doc["key1"]))
print(type(doc["key2"]))
```

Which prints:

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
```

But based on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) I expected the types to be

```
<class 'bson.decimal128.Decimal128'>
```

followed by something like 'bson.double'.

Why aren't I seeing a BSON `Decimal128` and a BSON `Double`? Is `type()` not the correct way to get the types in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python `float`s are stored as BSON `double`s. The API converts them on insertion and converts them back when querying.

If you want to store and retrieve BSON `Decimal128` values, use `bson.decimal128.Decimal128()`

```
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128

db = MongoClient()["mydatabase"]
collection = db["collection_test"]

collection.insert_one({"key1": Decimal128("1000000000.1"), "key2": Decimal128("1.1")})
doc = collection.find_one()
print(type(doc["key1"]))
print(type(doc["key2"]))
```

prints:

```
<class 'bson.decimal128.Decimal128'>
<class 'bson.decimal128.Decimal128'>
```

Documentation (albeit somewhat confusing):
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html

Also: be careful of using the `admin` database; it's a special database in MongoDB.